# How to render the component from property of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a navbar which contains few icons and titles.

To build it, I am using `react-icons` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons).
So, I am importing these items here

```
import { FaMobileAlt, FaCreditCard, FaRegBuilding } from 'react-icons/fa';
```

and I have a const responsible for keep the menu items list

```
const LEFT_MENU_ITEMS = [
  { key: 'devices', icon: FaMobileAlt, title: 'Devices' },
  { key: 'cards', icon: FaCreditCard, title: 'Cards' },
  { key: 'business', icon: FaRegBuilding, title: 'Business' },
];
```

The normal usage would be something like `<FaMobileAlt />` and thats it, but in my case I am trying to iterate over this const to build my list.

```
buildLeftMenuBar() {
if (!this.props.loggedIn) return null;
return (
  <ul key="leftMenuBar" className="items">
    {_.map(LEFT_MENU_ITEMS, itemDef => (
      <li key={itemDef.key}>
        <NavLink to={`/${itemDef.key}`}>
          <div>
          >>>>>  {itemDef.icon} <<<< 
          </div>
          <span>{itemDef.title}</span>
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

}

The error I get when render the page is

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render.

So, each icon isnt being rendered. How can I make it work following the same idea ?

ps: It's not only 3 items, I just removed some to make it easier to read the question, thats why I am trying to iterate.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar the icons isnt being rendered, just pointed the line with few arrows >> <<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use like this:

```
<itemDef.icon />
```

Instead of this:

```
{itemDef.icon}
```

Or, you may also use like:

```
{itemDef.icon()}
```

---

You might be wondering what's going in here. So, let me explain a little bit:

When you want to render a component say `MyComponent`, you will be able to print like:

```
{MyComponent()}
```

Or,

```
<MyComponent />
```

But not like:

```
{MyComponent}
```

Because, you will need to call the function. That's it.

---

As per your comment, you want to supply the size props in the component as you said:

```
<itemDef.icon size={20} />
```

And `{itemDef.icon()}` is not just limited. You can also pass the props here:

```
{itemDef.icon({size:20})} // component receives size props 20
```

Though, I would recommend to use `<itemDef.icon size={20} />` because it's little bit clear usage.

Comment: Yes and no. It will render the component, but you cant use attributes. <itemDef.icon size={20} />

Comment: yes, as I said it will render the component but its somehow limited to aditional attributes, like size, href, etc.

Comment: brilliant. Thanks for the explanation and example

Answer (score 2):

```
You can do it like this:

return(
  <ul key="leftMenuBar" className="items">
     {_.map(LEFT_MENU_ITEMS, item => {
        const Icon = item.icon;
        return (
            <li key={itemDef.key}>
                <NavLink to={`/${itemDef.key}`}>
                   <Icon />
                   <span>{itemDef.title}</span>
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        );
     })}
  </ul>
);
```